# Problems with iText 7 to create PDF in Android Studio 2021

Tags: java, android, pdf, gradle, itext7

I see iText 7 not working for me with AndroidStudio Chipmunk 2021.2.1.

I have tried these two implementation ways in the Gradle of my Android Studio project:

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itext7-core:7.1.8'
```

where the **PdfWriter, PdfDocument, Document and Paragraph classes** throw the error **"Cannot resolve symbol"**

And the other way of Implementation:

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:kernel:7.1.8'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:layout:7.1.8'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:io:7.1.8'
```

in this case **the Paragraph Class (from Layout) DOES NOT ADD the text I want.**

document.add(new Paragraph("Text for my Pdf"));

and the "Paragraph" doesn't work at all (it doesn't add any text to the PDF),
I add tables but no text.

Could you please help me with this form of implementation in Gradle or how to import the library ?

This is the code of my MainActivity

```
...
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument;
import com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.layout.Document;
import com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        try {
            createPdf();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException {
        String pdfPath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString();
        File file = new File(pdfPath, "myPDF.pdf");
        PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(String.valueOf(file));
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        // Adding paragraphs to document
        document.add(new Paragraph("Text for my PDF"));

       Table tabla = new Table(3); tabla.addCell("User"); 
       tabla.addCell("Name");
       tabla.addCell("Surname"); 

       for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){ 

        tabla.addCell(String.valueOf("Text " + i)); 
        tabla.addCell(String.valueOf("Text " + i)); 
        tabla.addCell(String.valueOf("Text " + i));
    } 
       document.add(tabla); 
       document.close();

        Toast.makeText(this, "The PDF document has been created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you attach the PDF file that you end up getting after trying to add a paragraph into it? Can you also try adding a table and a paragraph (you are saying adding tables works well) and attach the resultant PDF as well?

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine with the 2nd implementation of gradle and paragraph does add the text. so sharing the resultant pdf would make us understand the problem better.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I have also added the following code to check that the problem is only when adding text.
It turns out that I only get a small table with 3 columns and 6 rows (including the headers) and with all the cells empty

Comment: ```
Table tabla = new Table(3);
        tabla.addCell("User");
        tabla.addCell("Name");
        tabla.addCell("Surname");
        for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++){
            tabla.addCell(String.valueOf("Text " + i));
            tabla.addCell(String.valueOf("Text " + i));
            tabla.addCell(String.valueOf("Text " + i));
        }
        document.add(tabla);
        document.close();

```

Comment: The problem is that neither the text with Paragraph nor the text entered for each Cell of the table or headers is printed. the resulting Pdf only contains the empty and auto-adjusted table as for null texts (with minimum width and height)